# Absolute Beginner Looking to Produce a Primitive Music Video

Tags: sync, music

I am a total beginner to video. I don't even know what kind of camera I'll be using. (I'll have to borrow one.) I am just looking for an overview of what the general process will look like.

I have an audio track of a song I wrote. I want to make a 'music video' of myself turning over pages on which the lyrics are handwritten. So as the song plays, you would see me flipping over the pages. But I'd like to include 'cut-ins' from different video files. For example, at one point the song talks about walking, and I'd like to create an effect of footsteps appearing on the page in real time. So each 'frame' would have a new footstep. Hopefully that makes sense. Along with a few more 'cut' effects of that kind, which it seems to me would require splicing together different bits of video and getting the timing right.

So my specific questions are:

1) What's the best software to use for a project like this? Preferably free and able to operate on a Windows 10 laptop. I have Adobe Premiere Elements. The learning curve seems high, but so be it.

2) What's the general procedure for making sure that my audio and my video sync up correctly? I will be working with an existing file, so obviously I can't sync by creating the audio and the video simultaneously. I have to sync them after the fact. Is there a tried-and-true method for making this happen in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

This site does expect users to do a bit of effort before asking questions that have already been answered many times — the ol' "what's the best free software?" question has been asked so many times the paint's wearing off.

As for the second part, in any editor you have the ability to edit audio and video separately, so for a music video you lay down the music on one of the audio tracks, then cut your pictures so they work with the audio. You can move the pictures around independently of the audio and vice versa.

If there's video that needs to synch precisely, say if you're playing or singing and you want it to match the music, most NLEs (Non Linear Editors) have the ability to automatically synch two clips based on their audio.

Comment: Yeah, well, the ol' 'reprimand the self-proclaimed beginner looking for help' has worn pretty thin, too. If you're so out of patience with beginner's questions, maybe don't look at questions that start with 'Absolute Beginner'.

Comment: Have a look at the FAQ for this site. Questions and answers on this site are designed to be a resource for people with the same problem. Usually duplicate questions are flagged for removal, because the goal is to have all the answers for a particular question in the one place. I took the time to answer the part of the question that wasn't a dupe, maybe you should take the time to learn how this site works.